# Lookup Value in SQL Through Loops Until No Value Return

Tags: sql, loops

I work in manufacturing and there is a table in database which have BOM (kit part) Part Number and Component Part Number Mapping.

[BOM / COMP Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj7l5.png)

The complex part of the table is that, BOM part can be the component of another BOM part. In example above, part 111 and 112 is component of 121 but part 121 is also component of 141 and 141 is component of 151.

I currently have a list of lowest level component part number.

[Example of Component Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xdVy.png)

I hope to get list of BOM Parts from different levels. Not sure how do I approach this in SQL?

[Example of Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJbsn.png)

I know I can try to run select query multiple times to get the BOM Part Number and use that to find their BOM Part Number. However, I hope to check if there is a more efficient way to do that. Thank you!

Comment: You need a `Recursive CTE`, or similar. Syntax varies between DBMS. So, as per the SQL tag's notes, you Must specify which DBMS you're using.